# Is there an alternative to negative margins for item overlaying other item in css?

Tags: css

i have a markup like this:

```
<p>Image caption</p><img />
```

the p is an inline block.

I want the caption to overlay the image, rather than pushing the image to the left. Ususally I do this with margin-right -"x"px;, but as I don't know what width the image caption will have, I can't use this technique. Are there any good alternatives? (the text has a background color, so I cant' use block-elemnt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions written here were not possible for my site (although technically correct)

My solution was

```
<p>
    <span>Image caption<span>
</p>
<img />
```

and then

```
p{
    display:block;
    margin-right -100%;
}
```

some extra markup but hopefully it will help someone walking down the same path as I did!

Comment: Is the missing colon intentional?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about absolute positioning the items inside a div which is relatively positioned?

For example, wrap the p and img in a div and add position:relative to the div then add position:absolute to the p and the img and left or right position those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `div` around it:

```
<div><p>Image caption</p><img /></div>
```

Specify the width of the `div` and allow the `img` to be on top of the `p`. You can then use `padding: 0 auto;` on the div to center the image.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the p and img in a div.

```
<div>
<p>Image caption</p>
<img /> 
</div>
```

then use the below styling:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

you can adjust the top and left values accordingly and also use bottom or right instead of top and left if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use a fixed-size div and use your image as it's background?  That way any text would be overlaid without any need to mess around with absolute and relative positioning.
Mat

Comment: that's a great idea, although, the images are usercontent, so it would be a bit messy and bad markup...